# Connect to a remote firebird database

Tags: firebird

I have successfully stablished a VPN between my computer and another one in the internet.
I can share folders without a problem.
I need to connect to a firebird db located in the remote computer but I can't.
I attach a screenshot of what I am currently doing

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you are using a named pipes\WNET connection string, try using the TCP/IP variant (that is: remove the `\\\`).

Comment: I tried that without luck! Any other idea?

Comment: Is the port firewalled?

Comment: No, I disabled the firewall and I can acces the folder through the windows explorer.

Comment: That you can access a folder, does not necessarily mean that other services are accessible. BTW: What error do you get?

Comment: Hi! I have solved it. I used an alias instead of the path and it's working fine! Than you very much for your help Mark!